# Using (Preferably) C# Razor or JQuery to find which button opened the modal and setup modal dynamically

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

So we have some modals that are very similar in our ASP.Net MVC project and I want to set them up dynamically so that we don't have to have so many files strewn all over the place.

Once I've clicked a certain button and opened up the modal how do I check which button opened up the modal so I can do custom logic and inject specific html?

**Button #1 :**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary margin-bottom-5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newBugModal">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-plus"></i> New Bug
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="newBugModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="newBugModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    @Html.Partial("_bugModal")
</div>
```

**Button #2 :**

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bugEditModal">
    Edit
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="bugEditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="bugEditModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    @Html.Partial("_bugModal")
</div>
```

**Customizeable Modal :**

```
<div class="modal-dialog demo-modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                ×
            </button>
            <!-- CUSTOM LOGIC HERE (This is to set it as Bug Edit or New Bug)-->
            <h4 class="modal-title">Bug Edit || New Bug</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!-- CUSTOM LOGIC HERE (This is to set prefilled text or placeholder text)-->
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="bug" rows="5" required>Specific Bug Error</textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>           
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                Save Changes
            </button>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
```

I know this is probably something simple but I can't quite put my finger on it and also whether or not I should be using jQuery to accomplish this or just some Razor code. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

you could try passing the button selector id to the partial, something like this :

```
 @Html.Partial("_bugModal", new ViewDataDictionary { { "buttonId", "you-button-id"} });
```

in your partial just add a hidden field like this:

```
 <input type='hidden' id='some-id' value='@ViewBag.buttonId'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 action methods which returns 2 different partial view result, one for new and one for edit. Have your modal dialog get the remote content  based on the href attribute of the link clicked.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary margin-bottom-5 modal-link" href="@Url.Action("New","Bug")"  
    New Bug
</a>    
<a  class="btn btn-default modal-link" href="@Url.Action("Edit","Bug", new {id= 101 })" >
    Edit
</a>
```

and the client side code to load the remote content into modal

```
$(function(){
     $('body').on('click', '.modal-link',function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();

          $("#myModal").remove();
          $.get($(this).attr("href"),function (data) {
              $('<div id="myModal" class="modal fade"><div class="modal-dialog" 
                                                  role="document">' +data +'</div></div>')
                                .modal();
          });
   });

});
```

Assuming you have a New and Edit action method which returns the relevant partial view with markup needed for the modal dialog.

```
public ActionResult New()
{
  return PartialView();
}
```

and in the partial view for New,

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Add Bug</h4>
         <!-- add your form elements here as needed -->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit action method will be also same,But you accept the Id in the parameter and use that to build the view model needed for the edit partial view

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  var bugViewModel = GetBugViewModel(id);
  return PartialView(bugViewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin like [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/), and generate the modal in the event handler for each button:

**Markup:**

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default edit" data-id="some value">Edit</a>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary add">Add</a>
```

**jQuery:**

Your edit button should either store your lookup value as a data-attribute, or (if you prefer) as a sibling hidden input (use [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find it):

```
$('.btn.edit').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).data('id'); 

    /* your code to get the item data, template, whatever... */
    var value = "This is the current bug text";

    bootbox.prompt({
        title: 'Edit Bug',
        inputType: 'textarea',
        value: value,
        callback: function(result){
            if(result != ''){

                /* 
                    result will be a string value 
                    You'd add your persistence code here...
                */

            }
        }
    });
});
```

The add button would be similar:

```
$('.btn.add').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    bootbox.prompt({
        title: 'Add Bug',
        inputType: 'textarea',
        callback: function(result){
            if(result != ''){

                /* 
                    result will be a string value 
                    You'd add your persistence code here...
                */

            }
        }
    });
});
```

The advantage of a plugin like Bootbox is that you're not required to have the modal's markup on the page anywhere. With Bootbox specifically, the author has provided functions you can use in place of the native prompts (with the caveat that the Bootstrap modals do not block).

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.ajax()`

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/controller/action", //The action return partial views
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function() {
        //Your code.
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $("#modal-content").html(data);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Failed");
    }
})
```